# Three divs showing on hover css

Tags: html, css, hover

I have 3 divs and each should have a hover function to show text over the background image.

That works, sort of....  What is happening is when you hover over one all three show the text.  How can I fix it so only the one being hovered over shows?

For the css

```
.circleBase {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 185px;
  height: 185px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.c1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  height: 185px;
  width: 185px;
  background: url(../images/pencil2.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.c2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  height: 185px;
  width: 185px;
  background: url(../images/up.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.c3 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  height: 185px;
  width: 185px;
  background: url(../images/email.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.hidden1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 75px;
}

.hidden2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  display: none;
}

.hidden3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  display: none;
}

.full:hover .hidden1{
  display: block;
}

.full:hover .hidden2{
  display: block;
}

.full:hover .hidden3{
  display: block;
}
```

For the html I have

```
        <div class="full">
        <div class="box"><div class="circleBase c1"><a href="design.html" class="hidden1">Web Design</a></div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="circleBase c2"><a href="design.html" class="hidden2">SEO Services</a></div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="circleBase c3"><a href="design.html" class="hidden3">Contact Us</a></div></div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for reading!

Jim

Comment: And the CSS that isn't working properly..?

Comment: update the question, CSS part is missing.

Comment: Add the CSS instead of the second HTML. :)

Comment: Sorry guys I thought I had put it in there.....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you qualify correctly which div is being hovered in the selector, something like this:

```
.box:hover a{display:inline; /*or any value except none */ }
```

You were probably using the `.full` class, or just `div`

Comment: I got it guys!

Above I had full:hover but I tried to go a little deeper, do to speak.  I thought I had done that before but I guess I didn't.

Anyway, I changed the full:hover to circleBase:hover and it works now.

Thanks for reading everyone.